# lodash find in array

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have two arrays.

```
var loans = [
  { 'id': '1234', 'active': true, 'state': 'CA' },
  { 'id': '5678', 'active': false, 'state': 'IN' }
];

var people = [
    { 'id':'1', 'licenses': ["IN", "FL"] },
    { 'id':'2', 'licenses': ["CA"] }
];
```

I want to use lodash in order to find all the `people` who have a license in the loan of a state.

i have tried:

```
_find(loans, "IN");
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 7):

```
_.find(people, function(o) {
    return ~o.licenses.indexOf('IN');
});
// { 'id':'1', 'licenses': ["IN", "FL"] }
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had everything you had there at one point, but used 'contains' instead of "indexOf". Whoops! I appreciate your post!

Comment: that returns an object if only one returns.  How do I get this to stay an Array.  `people` was an Array going into the _.find() method.

Comment: `_.find()` will extract the first match, in your case, the object. If you want an array, you might be looking for `_.filter()`. Same syntax, but will return one or multiple matches as an array, and an empty array if no match is found.

Comment: If someone else is as confused as i am about the ~, your answer may be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators